# Listbox.SelectedItems.Add not causing SelectionChanged event

Tags: xaml, listbox

I have a custom user control extending the Listbox class.  Inside of it I am overriding OnSelectionChanged to add/remove Adorners to any selected/unselected items.  This all works when I select an item using the mouse, but when I programmatically add items to the listbox using

```
myListBox.SelectedItems.Add(newItem) // newItem is already a member of myListBox.Items
```

It does not execute the OnSelectionChanged code.

**Update**:  Unless I'm crazy (which is always possible) it seems there is a difference in behaviour between calling this from the parent object

```
myListBox.SelectedItems.Add(newItem)
```

and this method inside my extended listbox class

```
Public Sub AddSelectedItem(newItem as Object)
    Me.SelectedItems.Add(newItem)
End Sub
```

For some reason the second option is triggering the event while the first one isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here is that calling SelectedItems.Add() from inside an extension of ListBox

```
public class MyListBox : ListBox
{
public void AddSelectedItems(object newSelectedItem)
{
  // works
  this.SelectedItems.Add(newSelectedItem);
}
}
```

will trigger the OnSelectionChanged event.

Calling it like this from the window will not trigger the event

```
private sub SomeWindowMethod()
{
   // does not work
   this.MyListBoxInstance.SelectedItems.Add(newSelectedItem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this line of code first

```
myListBox.Items.Add(newItem)
```